# Why dplyr code which precomputes the maximum of a column is slower than dplyr code which computes it inside the mutate call?

Tags: r, microbenchmark, dplyr

Sample data frame:

```
ngroups <- 100
nsamples <- 1000
foo <- data.frame(engine = rep(seq(1, ngroups), each = nsamples), cycles = runif(ngroups*nsamples, 0, nsamples))
```

I want to find the `max` of `cycles` for each `engine` group, and create a new variable `tte = max(cycles) - cycles` with `mutate`. I thought that if I would precompute the column of maximum cycles, instead than recomputing it inside the `mutate` command for each row, the code would be faster. Turns out I'm wrong:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

add_tte <- function(dataset){
  dataset %<>% group_by(engine) %>% mutate(max_cycles = max(cycles)) %>% 
    mutate(tte = max_cycles - cycles) %>% select(-max_cycles) %>% ungroup
}

add_tte_old <- function(dataset){
  dataset %<>% group_by(engine) %>% mutate(tte = max(cycles) - cycles) %>% ungroup
}

microbenchmark(add_tte(foo), add_tte_old(foo), times = 500)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# add_tte(foo) 17.45324 21.107264 26.50535 24.52625 28.75208 113.98433   500
# add_tte_old(foo)  8.10376  9.949188 13.35830 12.18336 14.52474  77.64578   500
```

Why is this happening? Is the reason that `dplyr` computes the maximum just once for group, instead that once for row?

**EDIT**: even if I use a single `mutate` statement in `add_tte`, and I create a bigger example, `add_tte_old` is still faster

```
# these are the only lines of code modified, the rest is as before
nsamples <- 10000

foo <- data.frame(engine = rep(seq(1, ngroups), each = nsamples), cycles = runif(ngroups*nsamples, 0, nsamples))

add_tte <- function(dataset){
  dataset %<>% group_by(engine) %>% mutate(max_cycles = max(cycles), tte = max_cycles - cycles) %>%
  select(-max_cycles) %>% ungroup
}

# the new results are:
microbenchmark(add_tte(foo), add_tte_old(foo), times = 500)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# add_tte(foo) 90.46658 107.14015 139.13570 131.83689 158.24358 411.3272   500
# add_tte_old(foo) 39.38357  46.13531  62.57386  52.00782  69.26815 176.1512   500
```

Comment: I don't think that dplyr computes the max per row in the second example. It might be just because of the double `mutate` call which creates some additional overhead (and btw, is unnecessary since you can put multiple statements into a single mutate). You should probably benchmark on a larger example.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks for the tip about double  `mutate`: I fixed that and created a larger example, but `add_tte_old` still comes out on top.

Comment: If it's speed you are looking for, `data.table` is generally faster than `dplyr` on *large* data sets.

Comment: @DaveGruenewald thanks for the tip, but I'm going to stay with `dplyr`. My question is specifically to understand why the code that I would have thought to be faster (the one which precomputes the `max`) actually turns out to be slower. In other words, I want to understand which is the most efficient way to write code _in_ `dplyr`, not to write faster code with another package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made some wrong assumptions, but besides that, more importantly, you are not comparing like-wise.

It would make more sense to look at the two variants below:

```
add_tte <- function(dataset) {
  dataset %<>% group_by(engine) %>% mutate(max_cycles = rep(max(cycles), times = n()), tte = max_cycles - cycles) %>%
    select(-max_cycles) %>% ungroup
}

add_tte_old <- function(dataset) {
  dataset %<>% group_by(engine) %>% mutate(extra = rep(1, times = n()), tte = max(cycles) - cycles) %>%
    select(-extra) %>% ungroup
}

microbenchmark(add_tte(foo), add_tte_old(foo), times = 100)
```

On my machine, these two are pretty similar.

It is kind of ironic that with your way of attempting to pre-compute the `max(cycles)`, you probably did what you were trying to avoid :)

In the case here, you should really use the explicit `rep()` to fill up the column, whereas in the subtraction `max(cycles) - cycles` the auto-recycling is alright.

Comment: I see, the timings are indeed quite similar now. I don't understand what I did wrong, though. Can you elaborate on which wrong assumptions I made? If I understand what you're hinting to, basically `mutate(tte = max(cycles) - cycles)` is **not** recomputing `max(cycles)` for each element of the `cycles` subvector, but only once for `engine` group (which must be done anyway). So there's no need to try to save time by precomputing the max. Correct?